# An error happens in my Salesforce org. Nothing was returned from render

Tags: reactjs, salesforce, visualforce, react-modal

I write a react-modal code in visualforce page on my Salesforce environment, then error happened. How can i solve this?

```
          <Modal
          isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
          onRequestClose={this.toggleOpen}
                      heading="New Opportunity"
          >
          <h1>test</h1>
          </Modal>
```

Comment: can you show more code?

Comment: Code:
 state = {
  isOpen: false,
 };

 toggleOpen = () => {
  this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
 };

If you need to see other codes, please tell me!

Comment: can show the `render` funciton?

Comment: Sure, let me share my code in github.
https://github.com/MASA-JAPAN/Salesforce_MyDev/blob/master/Dev/force-app/main/default/pages/ContactSearchByReact.page

I added Modal component in line 137.
Also, currently I write codes to load cdn for Bootstrap.